# How to draw a concave arc programmatically?

Tags: java, android, ondraw

I want to draw a concave arc like on picture on a link. I have to animate this shape by changing its radius and position, so I can’t use images. 
So how can I draw this kind of figure with a concave arc on the bottom?

https://4.downloader.disk.yandex.ru/preview/0cb12c7fa3d900cbf198761ee7ed8d6d/mpfs/TfZ0SKvxnJVl4BOLkj7tO-JJUGVoNLdeNbtIPFP1XTaUMLjvrC4wbb8FZbeN1xyg9u_rL8IFN6LAEzrCmk7-6g%3D%3D?uid=0&filename=%D0%A1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B020150122%D0%B2175219png&disposition=inline&hash=&limit=0&content_type=image%2Fpng&size=XXL&crop=0

Comment: Please paste in the code that you have already attempted.

Comment: The easiest is probably the [Midpoint circle algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm).

Answer (score 0):

I built a general solution for creating / painting arcs, [located here](http://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/ui/util/PaintUtils.java). The class includes a main method which should help you understand how it works.